# creating assembly to generate code (reflection), but getting unknown exception

Tags: exception, reflection, .net-assembly, implicit

I am using the following to generate a method at runtime:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly currentAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters compilerParams = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters();
compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(currentAssembly.Location);
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider provider = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, code);
System.Reflection.Assembly newAssembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
newAssembly.GetType("NewOut.NewClass").GetMethod("newMethod").Invoke(null, args);
```

it takes in a "code" string and normally works fine. However some dynamically-generated code apparently refuses to compile, throwing this exception when CompiledAssembly is accessed:

"Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Documents and Settings\Dan\Local Settings\Temp\tkitti7h.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

The code SHOULD compile.

This code does compile, and works fine:

```
using Environment;

namespace NewOut{
public class NewClass{
    public NewClass(){
    }
    public static void newMethod(Color[,] data){
        int width = data.GetLength(0); int height = data.GetLength(1); for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){ for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){ Color brighter = data[x, y].brighten(0.4f).setRed(127); data[x, y] = brighter.toward(new Color("gray", 0.5), 0.5f); } }
    }
}
}
```

while this otherwise-IDENTICAL code, except for calling a different Color constructor, throws the exception:

```
using Environment;

namespace NewOut{
public class NewClass{
    public NewClass(){
    }
    public static void newMethod(Color[,] data){
        int width = data.GetLength(0); int height = data.GetLength(1); for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){ for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){ Color brighter = data[x, y].brighten(0.4f).setRed(127); data[x, y] = brighter.toward(new Color("gray"), 0.5f); } }
    }
}
}
```

Obviously if I paste that dynamically-generated code into an actual cs file it compiles and runs fine; there is nothing wrong with that single-argument constructor.

Of course, I've googled and the exception itself is common, and has to do with caching dlls, and whatnot, but I have not been able to find out how to view what the actual dynamically-invoked compiler is complaining about. I need to see the on-the-fly compilation error because there is clearly no actual problem with the dynamically-generated code.

So how can I view the actual error?

I should note besides the Color(string) constructor, implicit conversion from string to Color also throws the CompiledAssembly exception when I try to use that in the dynamically-compiled code. I suspect a connection there, especially since I have noticed in the past that the C# compiler tends to invoke that implicit string-to-Color conversion sometimes for no reason at all (faulty optimization?). But regardless of that I am not aware of any limitations of dynamic compilation related to implicit conversion.

Unless someone instantly knows why my string constructor and string implicit conversion fail when dynamically compiled, I am hoping that someone can give me easy directions to view the actual dynamic compiler error, because the "unable to load file or assembly" isn't helping.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you at least format your code so we humans can read it?

Comment: You mean the dynamically-generated newMethod()? It's not that hard to read. It's in one line because my dynamic generation doesn't bother making it look too pretty, it's only support to run and the disappear. But what it does doesn't matter, the only difference between the working and non-working is that a different constructor overload is called

Comment: You can view the compiler errors from `results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, code);`. I can only assume the second snippet did not compiler correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I have it working now even though I actually don't know what was wrong. The snippet was technically correct but didn't work until I added referenced assemblies (various System. assemblies which were referenced by the current assembly), even though the snippet didn't actually reference any of them. The code works now, although for some reason it says "type or namespace name 'object' could not be found" if the dynamically compiled code explicitly uses the Object class (even though the core System dll is included, and int, float, etc work). But I don't need to use Object. Thanks again!